# How to get different results running sklearn's MeanShift in a single program? (Python3)

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I ran into a quirk with sklearn's MeanShift that I don't know how to get around.

MeanShift doesn't predictably give the same results on every run, so I wanted to run it multiple times within one program, but the results are the same on every iteration. They are different across program runs, but the same over every loop.

Minimal code sans `convert_non_numerical_data(...)`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.cluster import MeanShift
from sklearn import preprocessing

# EDIT: added on request 
def convert_non_numerical_data_to_numerical(data_frame):
    columns = data_frame.columns.values

    for col in columns:
        text_digit_vals = {}

        if data_frame[col].dtype in [np.int64, np.float64]:
            continue

        x = 0
        for unique in set(data_frame[col].values):
            if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                x += 1

        def convert_to_int(val):
            return text_digit_vals[val]
        data_frame[col] = list(map(convert_to_int, data_frame[col]))

df = pd.read_csv("test_data/titanic.csv")
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)  # bad idea to shove in 0?
convert_non_numerical_data_to_numerical(df)

y = np.array(df["survived"])
X = np.array(df.drop(["survived"], 1))
X = preprocessing.scale(X)

run_data = []
for run_count in range(3):
    clf = MeanShift()
    clf.fit(X)
    run_data.append(clf.labels_.copy())
    clf = None

run_0 = run_data[0]
for other_run in run_data[1:]:
    if np.array_equiv(run_0, other_run):
        print("same")
    else:
        print("different")
```

Output:

```
same
same
```

Any idea what is causing this, or at least how to get around it?

Note:

- Data set from [pythonprogramming.net](https://pythonprogramming.net/static/downloads/machine-learning-data/titanic.xls)

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at smoothing your dataset with any other methods? What hyper-parameter tuning have you done? Also how did you convert your non_numerical data, just wondering if you can provide pastbin?

Comment: OP edited to include function. It is a simple indexer. I don't think that this is about data smoothing, but I don't know enough to say for certain. It seems to be an issue of the first run's data sticking around and not changing, or maybe the original clustering centers are static. I don't know why three runs of the program could produce slightly different clustering results, but three iterations in one run of the program produces the same results.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of work arounds:
1- Set `bin_seeding` to True, and/or using random seeds at each iteration.
2- Shuffling the data at each iteration.